# how to pass values with respective update table in mysql

Tags: mysql

When I call the stored procedure passing in lists of data as input:

```
IN pk VARCHAR(MAX)  = “11;12;13”
IN forenam varchar(MAX)= “Test1;Test2;Test3”
IN surnam varchar(MAX) = “Tst1;Tst2;Tst3”
IN bdate varchar(MAX) = “2016-01-02; 2016-01-04; 2016-01-03”
IN comm varchar(MAX) = “Comments1;comm2;comm3”
IN table_nam varchar(MAX)= “Name1”
```

It should update the table named “Name1” as below in one call to SP

```
PK  forename    surname bdate   comments
11  Test1   Tst1    2016-01-02  Comments1
12  Test2   Tst2    2016-01-04  comm2
13  Test3   Tst3    2016-01-03  comm3`





CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_UKFLMM_Update_multitable`(
IN pk int, 
IN forenam varchar(255), 
IN surnam varchar(255), IN bdate datetime,
IN comm varchar(1000), 
IN table_nam varchar(255))
BEGIN

if table_nam in ('UK_FLMM_demandData','UK_FLMM_Completed_demandData')
then 
UPDATE table_nam set forename=forenam,surname=surnam,birthDate=bdate,comments=comm where id=pk;

else if table_nam = 'UK_FLMM_sequenceData' then

UPDATE table_nam set comments=comm where id=pk;

end if;
end if;


END$$

DELIMITER
```

I have tried the above SP but its updating only one row at a time.So can anyone please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing below condition in where clause

```
WHERE LOCATE(REPLACE(id,';',','),pk) > 0;
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

This will update multiple records. But will update `'Comments1;comm2;comm3'` to all the three ids.

If you need to update like below

```
id comm
1  Comments1
2  comm2
3  comm3
```

Then this will not work.

In that case you can follow below SP

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_UKFLMM_Update_multitable`(
IN pk int, 
IN forenam varchar(255), 
IN surnam varchar(255), IN bdate datetime,
IN comm varchar(1000), 
IN table_nam varchar(255))
BEGIN

    DECLARE loopIncrement INT;
    DECLARE loopLimit INT;
    DECLARE nPK INT;
    DECLARE nForeName varchar(255);
    DECLARE nSurName varchar(255);
    DECLARE nBDate datetime;
    DECLARE nComm varchar(1000);

    SET loopLimit := 0;
    SET loopIncrement := 0;

    SET loopLimit := (LENGTH(pk) - LENGTH(REPLACE(pk,";",""))) + 1;

WHILE loopIncrement < loopLimit DO
    IF(loopIncrement = loopLimit - 1) THEN
        SET nPK := SUBSTRING_INDEX(pk,';',-1);
        SET nForeName := SUBSTRING_INDEX(forenam,';',-1);
        SET nSurName := SUBSTRING_INDEX(surnam,';',-1);
        SET nComm := SUBSTRING_INDEX(comm,';',-1);
        SET nBDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(bdate,';',-1);
    ELSE    
        SET nPK := SUBSTRING_INDEX(pk,';',loopIncrement+1);
        SET nForeName := SUBSTRING_INDEX(forenam,';',loopIncrement+1);
        SET nSurName := SUBSTRING_INDEX(surnam,';',loopIncrement+1);
        SET nComm := SUBSTRING_INDEX(comm,';',loopIncrement+1);
        SET nBDate := SUBSTRING_INDEX(bdate,';',loopIncrement+1);
    END IF;

    if table_nam in ('UK_FLMM_demandData','UK_FLMM_Completed_demandData')
    then 
    UPDATE table_nam set forename=nForeName,surname=nSurName,birthDate=nBDate,comments=nComm where id=nPK;

    else if table_nam = 'UK_FLMM_sequenceData' then

    UPDATE table_nam set comments=nComm where id=nPK;

    loopIncrement++;

end if;
end if;

END WHILE;  


END$$

DELIMITER
```

**NOTE: This is just a sample SP which implements your scenario to get start with. Improve it if you face any issue.**

Comment: id comm
1  Comments1
2  comm2
3  comm3

Comment: I don't want to will update 'Comments1;comm2;comm3' to all the three ids

Comment: I have updated the answer which solves your problem.